# How to return boolean and not string when using select?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this:-

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Allow Multiple</label>
                <select class="form-control" v-model="allowMultiple">
                    <option value=true>Yes</option>
                    <option value=false>No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

I set `allowMultiple=true` when I initialize it, but when I select No then `allowMultiple='false'` So its no longer a Boolean but a String? How to get it to be Boolean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In HTML, if you set attribute value in a tag, the value will be default type--`string`.So you can use vue `v-model` in combination with `:value` to bind it to other type value, for example, Boolean, Number and etc.
Following code is working, the result is what you want

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    allowMultiple: false
  },
  methods: {
    print: function () {
      alert(this.allowMultiple);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id='app'>
   <label for="">Allow Multiple</label>
   <select class="form-control" v-model="allowMultiple" @change='print'>
        <option :value='true'>Yes</option>
        <option :value='false'>No</option>
   </select>
<div>
    Type: {{ typeof allowMultiple }},
    Value: {{ allowMultiple }} 
</div>

</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do you mean I should do <option v-model=true>Yes</option>?

Comment: does not work:  ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                       2:25:13 PM

 error  in ./resources/assets/js/components/content_type_blocks/blocks/TaxonomyBlock.vue

Syntax Error: Assigning to rvalue (151:8)

Comment: `v-model='true'` but not `v-model=true`

Comment: same, already tried both varations, even my editor goes creazy over that syntax and everything after that becomes different color then it should

Comment: you also modify `allowMultiple` to `true`?

Comment: can you get this working on your side? What you suggest I already have tried and have set allowMultiple: true when initializing it. Somebody edited this post a put '' around true and false

Comment: I'm so sorry, i'm not in home now. I will display it to you when i arrive home.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Just be sure to use the binding syntax when defining your options: `v-bind:value="true"` or the shorthand `:value="true"`.  This syntax is briefly, but inadequately, discussed in the [Form Input Bindings documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select-Options).

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way to do it in Vue.
Instead of hard coding your options in html. Use the Vue way, set an array of options in your Vue data then use `v-for` to render all the options from the array.

Each option should have 2 properties: a text and a value. The value should be the boolean you are looking for.

Now whenever the user changes the selected option, it will always be boolean.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    allowMultiple: true,
    options: [
      {text: 'Yes', value: true},
      {text: 'No', value: false},
    ],
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group">

      <div>Allow multiple: {{allowMultiple}}  [Type: {{typeof allowMultiple}}]</div><br>

      <label for="">Allow Multiple</label>
      <select class="form-control" v-model="allowMultiple">
          <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

The easier and quicker way I found that works for me is this:

```
<select id="selected" v-model="item.selected">
    <option :value=0>No</option>
    <option :value=1>Yes</option>
</select>
```

Maybe it's useful for anyone.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<option value=1>Yes</option>
<option value=0>No</option>
```

Comment: I tried that, still returns 1 and 0 as a string '1' and '0'. wonder why it does that? Can you test on your end?

Comment: use parseInt(value) at javascript side

Comment: javascript side? this is vue, this is javascript side, it is is vue component in its own file, there is no other javascript side